# Add components to parent div dynamically in vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I have a parent component which adds some subcomponents based on API response.

Parent component already has few components added beforehand and I would like to append new ones to it.

```
<div class="subwalletContainer">
    <sub-wallet />
    <sub-wallet />
    <sub-wallet />    
</div>
```

In the above div I want to append another component based on API response.
Can $mount help in this case? I cannot go for a v-for approach as multiple different components types are coming from different sources.

Comment: share live demo or snippet of this. also add which component you want ?

Comment: @C2486 say I want to add another instance of sub-wallet component . Can I use appendChild in this case ?

Comment: Yes its possible .Can you share you live snippet or any demo ?

Comment: Its a bit difficult to share a working demo as I am newbie in vuejs .If you refer here http://jsfiddle.net/h5a2e0gr/ I am using a single file components.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your approach a little bit, when using Vue you should not think about adding/removing anything from DOM directly. You should modify your data, which in turn will lead to changes in your DOM.

I think what you are looking for is dynamic [components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

```
<!-- Component changes when currentTabComponent changes -->
<component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>
```